# Mapping Array of Arrays into a List

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, list, map-function

I have an Array of answers, sorted by the question they belong to, like this:

[image: how the array appears in console]

```
    sortedAnswers= [[Answer1, Answer2, Answer3, Answer4],[AnswerA, AnswerB, AnswerC, AnswerD]...]
```

I'm trying to render a list of ListItemButton in React. I've tried with

```xml
    <ButtonGroup
      fullWidth
      orientation='vertical'
      onClick={handleSubmit}
      onChange={handleChange}
    >
      {sortedAnswers.map((item) =>
        <ListItemButton>{item}</ListItemButton> )}
    </ButtonGroup>
```

but it doesn't work as expected and I get this:

[image: quiz_card]

I'd love to get one ListItemButton for each answer, so 4 buttons for each question. How can I get just the answer of the first array in the buttons?

Comment: so in this case 'item' is an array, correct?

Comment: @terpinmd yes, it shoud be, but if I try with ITEM[0] it returns only Answer1 and AnswerA because they are at the position 0 in each array. I want to display just the Answers of one of the arrays, so for example for question1 i wanto to display from answer1 to answer4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned `error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`, add a conditional check before you map over it.

```
{sortedAnswers.length > 0 && (
  <ButtonGroup fullWidth orientation='vertical' onClick={handleSubmit} onChange={handleChange}>
    {sortedAnswers[0].map((answer, index) => (
      <ListItemButton key={index}>{answer}</ListItemButton>
    ))}
  </ButtonGroup>
)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want your layout to look like use a nested loop to iterate all answers:

```
const sortedAnswers = [
  [Answer1, Answer2, Answer3, Answer4],
  [AnswerA, AnswerB, AnswerC, AnswerD]
];

{sortedAnswers.map(answers => (
  <ButtonGroup
    fullWidth
    orientation="vertical"
    onClick={handleSubmit}
    onChange={handleChange}
  >
    {answers.map(answer => (
      <ListItemButton>{answer}</ListItemButton>
    ))}
  </ButtonGroup>
))}
```

Comment: I tried but it returns all the answers, so i have 8 buttons, I just need the answers from the first array

Comment: In that case @Elerua's answer looks correct to me. If you're getting an error there, please share your exact `sortedAnswers` array.

Comment: @Elerua's I've added a picture of the console log of the array, if you want to check. I'm sure the problem is the nature of the array but I don't get it

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the answers of the first array in the buttons I would have built it like this :

```js
<ButtonGroup fullWidth orientation='vertical' onClick={handleSubmit} onChange={handleChange}>
  {sortedAnswers[0].map((answer, index) => (
    <ListItemButton key={index}>{answer}</ListItemButton>
  ))}
</ButtonGroup>
```

Comment: I've tried but if I try it gives me this error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')